# How to use useState hook with Preact and no build tools?

Tags: javascript, preact

Currently I need to get a Preact application working without any build tools, just with an index.html with the import statements to get preact from the CDN. I'm able to import the `useState` hook from the CDN no problem, and even able to console.log() the value of the function `useState`, but whenever I try to use it, I get an error saying:

['Uncaught TypeError: u is undefined'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhPSQ.png)

Do ya'll happen to know why this is the case? I have tried to use the `useState` function inside of the functional component, and outside and it doesn't work either way. Am I missing something here? Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="module">
        import { h, Component, render } from 'https://unpkg.com/preact?module';
        import { useState } from 'https://unpkg.com/preact@latest/hooks/dist/hooks.module.js?module'
        import htm from 'https://unpkg.com/htm?module';

        // Initialize htm with Preact
        const html = htm.bind(h);
      
        const App = (props) => {

            const [testVar, setTestVar] = useState(0);

            var countVariable = 0;

            const incrementButtonHandler = () => {
                countVariable = countVariable + 1;
            }

            const logMethod = () => {
                console.log(countVariable);
                countVariable = countVariable + 1;
            }

          return html`<div>
            <h1>Test ${props.name}!: ${countVariable}</h1>
            <button onClick=${logMethod}>Increment</button>
          </div>`;
        }
      
        render(html`<${App} name="World" />`, document.body);
      </script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a known bug and limitation in what unpkg can do, see: https://github.com/preactjs/preact/issues/2571

There's a couple easy fixes though:

1. Use already resolved URLs for each module (notice the `@latest` in the preact import)

```js
import { h, render } from 'https://unpkg.com/preact@latest?module'
import { useState } from 'https://unpkg.com/preact@latest/hooks/dist/hooks.module.js?module'
import { html } from 'https://unpkg.com/htm/preact/index.module.js?module'
```

2. Use a CDN without this issue, like [skypack](https://skypack.dev), instead:

```js
import { h, render } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/preact';
import { useState } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/preact/hooks';
import { html } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/htm/preact';
```

Either should work.

Answer (score 1):

[rchristian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69905913/6243352) is useful, but the module-imported hooks appear to fail when using a router. Here's a minimal repro*.

(If you have trouble navigating to the `/about` route in the snippets, you may need to run them locally since the iframe doesn't play well with routing on all browsers, notably Chrome at the time of writing.)

```html
<script type="module">
import {h, render, Component} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/preact";
import {useState} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/preact/hooks";
import {Router} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/preact-router";
import htm from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/htm";
const html = htm.bind(h);

const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const increment = () => {
    setCount(prevState => prevState + 1);
  };

  return html`
    <button onClick=${increment}>
      Count: ${count}
    </button>
  `;
};

const Nav = () => html`
  <nav>
    <a href="/">home</a> | <a href="/about">about</a>
  </nav>
`;
const Home = () => html`
  <p>Home</p>
  <${Counter} />
`;
const About = () => html`
  <p>About</p>
`;
const App = () => html`
  <header>
    <${Nav} />
  </header>
  <main>
    <${Router}>
      <${Home} path="/" />
      <${About} path="/about" />
      <${Home} default />
    <//>
  </main>
`;

render(html`<${App} />`, document.querySelector("#app"));
</script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Starting at the home route, you'll see the counter component works fine. Navigate to the about route, then back to home and you'll see `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: u is null` from the hooks script.

I'd much prefer the module imports so I'd be curious to hear how to fix the above code, but I did manage to work around this with the following UMD approach:

```html
<script type="module">
const {h, render, Component} = preact;
const {useState, useEffect} = preactHooks;
const {Router} = preactRouter;
import htm from "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/htm/3.1.1/htm.module.js";
const html = htm.bind(h);

const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const increment = () => {
    setCount(prevState => prevState + 1);
  };

  return html`
    <button onClick=${increment}>
      Count: ${count}
    </button>
  `;
};

const Nav = () => html`
  <nav>
    <a href="/">home</a> | <a href="/about">about</a>
  </nav>
`;
const Home = () => html`
  <p>Home</p>
  <${Counter} />
`;
const About = () => html`
  <p>About</p>
`;
const App = () => html`
  <header>
    <${Nav} />
  </header>
  <main>
    <${Router}>
      <${Home} path="/" />
      <${About} path="/about" />
      <${Home} default />
    <//>
  </main>
`;

render(html`<${App} />`, document.querySelector("#app"));
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/preact/10.7.2/preact.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/preact/10.7.2/hooks.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/preact-router/4.0.1/preact-router.umd.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

This is similar to [Jason Miller's Router example](https://jsfiddle.net/developit/qc73v9va/) but also uses hooks.

---

* This is a known issue as developit has a couple of code sandbox repros:

- https://codesandbox.io/s/7z5id?file=/index.html
- https://codesandbox.io/s/htm-preact-hooks-router-jspm-0jhg9